# React unit testing - accessing querystring parameters off the match object

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing

I am trying to test a React component against various querystring options. This is a simplified version of my test code.

```
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { act, render } from '@testing-library/react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router } from 'react-router-dom';

const defaultProps = {
    match: { params: { id: 1 } },
};

act(async () => {
    render(
        <Provider store={mockStore()}>
            <Router>
                <ComponentToTest {...defaultProps} />
            </Router>
        </Provider>
    );
});
```

However, the match object is somehow being overwritten (I suspect by the Router) to:

```
{ path: '/', url: '/', params: {}, isExact: true }
```

The ComponentToTest is looking for match as a top level property.

```
export const ComponentToTest = ({ match, history }) => {
    // Stuff here which uses redux, match and history
};
```

How should I be passing in the match data into this component?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Solved it.

My ComponentToTest has a default export utilising withRouter:

```
export const ComponentToTest = ({ match, history }) => {
    // Stuff here which uses redux, match and history
};

export default withRouter(ComponentToTest);
```

And I was importing that one into my test rather than the plain one.

e.g.

Doing this

```
import { ComponentToTest } from './index';
```

rather than

```
import ComponentToTest from './index';
```

Fixed it.